# Best approach instead of granting permissions all the time to logins

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2014

So, I'm trying to fix logins/users permissions here ( everybody was using DBO for everything, weak passwords and etc ).

For each customer we have, I will create only one login. It will access test databases, [homologation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homologation), and etc.

I will give the login these permissions:

```
USE [master]
GO
CREATE LOGIN [User_Customer] 
WITH PASSWORD=N'Strong_Pass', 
DEFAULT_DATABASE=[Customer_DB], 
CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF
GO

ALTER SERVER ROLE [bulkadmin] ADD MEMBER [Customer_DB]--BULK
GO

USE Customer_DB
GO
CREATE USER [User_Customer]     FOR LOGIN [User_Customer] --User
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [User_Customer] --DR
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER [User_Customer] --DW
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin]   ADD MEMBER [User_Customer] --DDL
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO [User_Customer] --EXECUTE
GO
USE [master]
GO
DENY VIEW ANY database to [User_Customer] --DENY
```

Is there a way to create a single role, where I can only crate the role, and assign the users mapped to this login, to the role?

I don't want to sometime forget a permission and mess everything.

I appreciate any tips about how to manage logins and users better than what I'm currently doing.

(The above script is for sql 2014. It's just for you guys to get the Idea. with sql server 2008, it's a different way ( sp_addrolemember and etc ).

Comment: My answer at https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125403/8783 will help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a single role, where I can only crate the
>   role, and assign the users mapped to this login, to the role?

Yes you can do exactly as you said, create a `role`, add it as a member to the roles you are interested in and `grant` it permissions the same way you did it with a single `user`:

```
create role MyCustomRole;

ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER MyCustomRole--[User_Customer] --DR
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datawriter] ADD MEMBER MyCustomRole--[User_Customer] --DW
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_ddladmin]   ADD MEMBER MyCustomRole--[User_Customer] --DDL
GO
GRANT EXECUTE TO MyCustomRole--[User_Customer] --EXECUTE
GO
```

Now you can add your users to this `role`:

```
alter role MyCustomRole add member [User_Customer];
```

To control what `permissions` your user has now just `impersonate` it:

```
execute as user = 'User_Customer';

select *
from sys.fn_my_permissions(null, 'database');

revert;
```

---

One tip for `SQL Server 2014`:

I saw you want to deny `view any database` to your `logins`.

After such a `deny` your logins will not see `databases` in `Object Explorer`, I mean all the `databases` included those where they are mapped to.

I think it will render their work more complicated. I don't know what exactly reasons led you to this decision, but if you really need it maybe `Contained databases` appeared in `2012` is the solution for you.

When you make a database `contained`, it's database itself that `authenticates` your `users`.
This way you do not need `logins` anymore, every `user` can be created in its own database directly and will "see" only that database in `Object Explorer`.

More on `contained databases` here:
[SQL Server 2012 Contained Database Feature](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2428/sql-server-2012-contained-database-feature/)

Comment: Nice, thanks about your post. Oh and I know about the `view any databases`. Users will not login with it in management studio. Only devs, but they have their own windows login.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a particular naming convention for these customer logins, you could create a server-scoped [DDL Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers) on the `CREATE_LOGIN` event. I mention a naming convention because you will need to filter out logins you want to add permissons to so that you don't apply this logic to all `CREATE LOGIN` statements.

In this trigger, you should be able to apply all of these role memberships and grants, both the server-level ones and the database-level ones. You won't need a new database-level role for the five database-level permissions because there is no chance of forgetting one of them (it's in the code). You will probably need to use Dynamic SQL to achieve this, but there is no user input so I don't see any harm in it.